# Vitamio library makes apk file too big

Tags: android, vitamio

I'm trying to use Vitamio SDK but when I'm adding the library to my project the apk becomes too big (approximately 20Mb and bigger).

I add the library as a project in Eclipse.

I think, I should add .jar library but when I do I get ExceptionInInitializerError while running LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs method.

Comment: Please check my asnwer here : http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824933/1572408
 Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

From Vitamio 4.1 has support full version and online version, you can use online version.
[ChangeLog](https://github.com/yixia/VitamioBundle/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#version-410-2013-08-30)

Vitamio 4.x support custom ffmpeg, you can recompile ffmpeg.

Answer (score 0):

As I've stated here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/20954179/606351), Vitamio comes bundled with compiled bins for a variety of processors. It unpacks the right one upon initialization.

You can weed out some of these but you would lose cross-platform support.
Or you could recompile FFMpeg to contain only the portions you're gonna use.