# Android Vitamio library makes apk too big

Tags: android, video, android-videoview, video-player, vitamio

I'm trying to use Vitamio library. My apk without Vitamio is about 400k , and when I add Vitamio's library it become more than 11 MB ! I just want to use Vitamio's videoView. Is it any way to customize the library ? I started copying and pasting necessary classes from the library but they are a lot! 
Please give me some advice and thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Also I insert the jar file in libs folder instead of adding the library and it's just about 50kb. This time when I run the app, it says in a dialog that I have to install the Vitamio app first to continue :/

Comment: there's no such abbreviation as "MG" unless you meant "Mega Gigabyte". If you meant megabytes, then "MB" or "MiB".

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski u r right mate, sorry , I just fixed it, lol

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the libarm.so file will NOT fix your situation.
This file contains native libs for a variety of processros. The Vitamio library extracts the correct one upon first initialization, to a private directory inside the app's data/data directory.

Deleting the 11MB file will make your app uninstallable.

Look at `InitActivity.java` and `Vitamio.java`.